# Returning an element of a list based on an id

Tags: java, guava

Does anyone know of any fancy guava function that will do the following for me.

Consider I have a list of object. Each object has an id. I have a list of 10 objects with ids from 1 to 10. I want to get at a particular object based on an id. What I usually do is

```
private MyObject findMyObjectById(List<MyObject> items, Integer id) {
   for (MyObject item : items) {
      if (id.equals(item.getId())) {
          return item;
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is both verbose and repetitive as I cant type id (getId is not in any interface I have for various reasons)

Is there any fancy guava way to do this?

Comment: If the operation is frequent, is there any particular reason you're using `List<MyObject>` for storage and not - for example - something like `HashMap<Integer, MyObject>()`?

Comment: Java 8 something like `items.stream().filter(it -> it.getId.equals(id)).findFirst().orElse(null)`

Comment: groovy one-liner: `items.find{ it.id == id }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I use [FluentIterable's firstMatch](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html).

Also in most cases avoid returning null, prefer [Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html).

```
private final int id;

public MyObject(final int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyObject [id=" + this.id + "]";
}

public static Optional<MyObject> findFirstByFilter(final List<MyObject> myObjects, final Predicate<MyObject> filter) {

    return FluentIterable.from(myObjects)
            .firstMatch(filter);
}

public static Optional<MyObject> findFirstById(final List<MyObject> myObjects, final Integer id) {

    return findFirstByFilter(myObjects, new Predicate<MyObject>() {

        @Override
        public boolean apply(final MyObject myObject) {

            return myObject.getId() == id;
        }
    });
}

public static void main(final String... args) {
    final List<MyObject> myObjects = ImmutableList.of(new MyObject(1), new MyObject(2));

    final Optional<MyObject> found = findFirstById(myObjects, 2);

    //MyObject [id=2]
    System.out.println(found.orNull());

    final Optional<MyObject> notFound = findFirstById(myObjects, 5);

    //null
    System.out.println(notFound.orNull());
}
```

Java 8 version:

```
private final int id;

public MyObject(final int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyObject [id=" + this.id + "]";
}

public static void main(final String... args) {

    final List<MyObject> myObjects = ImmutableList.of(new MyObject(1), new MyObject(2));

    final Optional<MyObject> found = myObjects.stream()
        .filter(myObject -> myObject.getId() == 2)
        .findAny();

    // MyObject [id=2]
    System.out.println(found.orElse(null));

    final Optional<MyObject> notFound = myObjects.stream()
        .filter(myObject -> myObject.getId() == 5)
        .findAny();

    // null
    System.out.println(notFound.orElse(null));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you can't always modify your code to suite, but this is a pattern I saw on here somewhere (I can't find it now).  We now use this a lot on our Entity objects, DTO's etc.

Create this interface:

```
public interface HasLongId {
  public long getId();
}
```

Now in a LongIds class:

```
public static final Function<HasLongId, Long> GetIndex =
    new Function<HasLongId, Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long apply(HasLongId hasId) {
            return hasId.getId();
        }
    };
public static class NameMatcher implements Predicate<HasLongId> {
    private final long id;
    public NameMatcher(long id) {   
        this.id = id;   
    } 
    @Override public boolean apply(HasLongId hasId) { 
        return id == hasId.getId(); 
    }
}
```

With that you can do:

```
public static final <V extends HasLongId> Iterator<Long> of(Iterator<V> items) {
    return Iterators.transform(items, GetIndex);
}
public static final <V extends HasLongId> String join(Iterable<V> items) {
    return Joiner.on(',').skipNulls().join(of(items));
}
public static final <V extends HasLongId> ImmutableMap<Long, V> mapOf(Iterable<V> items)     {
    return Maps.uniqueIndex(items, GetIndex);
}
public static final <V extends HasLongId> V find(Iterable<V> iterable, Long id) {
    return Iterables.find(iterable, new NameMatcher(id));
}
public static final <V extends HasLongId> boolean contains(V[] array, Long id) {
    return Iterators.contains(of(Iterators.forArray(array)), id);
}
```

and so on.
We also have this interface:

```
public interface HasName  {
    String getName();
}
```

Along with a class called Names which contains our utility methods.
Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, `Iterables` has a [find](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#find(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)) method which takes a [Predicate](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html). I am not sure how "fancy" it is, you would have to implement a `Predicate` class which does the id comparison.

I will echo @JoachimIsaksson, though, this seems like you really would benefit from a `Map<Integer,MyObject>`.